# It is necessary that when you click on "block one", the rest of the blocks are closed, how to release this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i need that when I click on one block, it opens an input (already implemented), and another block get closed, please help. Here is my code: i've already realized onClick input appearing, but cant handle with other

```
function App() {
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false)
const [isClosed, setIsClosed] = useState(false)

const handleCheck = () => {
    setIsChecked(isChecked => !isChecked)
}
const handleClose = () => {
    setIsClosed(isClosed => !isClosed)
}
```

return (

```
<div className="App">

    <div onClick={handleCheck}>block one</div>
    {isChecked &&
    <input/>
    }
    <div onClick={handleClose}>block two</div>
    {isClosed &&
    <input/>
    }


</div>
```

);
}

Comment: I need "block two" to get closed when i click on "block one" which gets its input 
and and also vice versa with other block

Comment: More details: when you click on block one, an input should drop out under it, and block two should hide. The input is already shown, the problem is that I don't know how to hide block two when clicking on the first

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { useState } from "react"
export default function App() {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false)
  const [isClosed, setIsClosed] = useState(false)
    
    const handleCheck = () => {
      setIsChecked(true)
      setIsClosed(false)
  }
  const handleClose = () => {
      setIsClosed(true)
      setIsChecked(false)
  }
    return(
      <div className="App">

        <div onClick={handleCheck}>block one</div>
        {isChecked &&
        <input/>}
        
        <div onClick={handleClose}>block two</div>
        {isClosed && 
        <input/>}
        


    </div>
    )

}
```

Comment: I've already did this, why'd u rewrite my code? I need other blocks closing when i click on certain block

Comment: More details: when you click on block one, an input should drop out under it, and block two should hide.
The input is already shown, the problem is that I don't know how to hide block two when clicking on the first

Comment: bro, I didn't rewrite your code. There is a difference . Have you tried my code before commenting.

Comment: yes, i've tried. You code calls input under blocks. My previous code did the same thing, except that the function to show or hide the input worked for me, and your code only shows input. Write what i needed to solve my problem again pls and try your code by urself. I've already found the solution, you can check what i needed in the bottom of my question's page.

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
function App() {
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(true)
const [isClosed, setIsClosed] = useState(true)

const handleCheck = () => {
    setIsChecked(isChecked => !isChecked)
}
const handleClose = () => {
    setIsClosed(isClosed => !isClosed)
}
return (

<div className="App">

    <div onClick={handleClose}>block one</div>
    {isChecked &&
    <input/>
    }
    <div onClick={handleCheck}>block two</div>
    {  isClosed &&
    <input/>
    }


</div>
); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done my problem by myself. Here is my code:

```
 import { useState } from "react"
export default function App() {
    const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false)
    const [isClosed, setIsClosed] = useState(false)

    const handleCheck = () => {
        setIsChecked(isChecked => !isChecked)
    }
    const handleClose = () => {
        setIsClosed(isClosed => !isClosed)
    }
    return(
        <div className="App">
            {
                isClosed ? null : <div onClick={handleCheck}>block one</div>
            }
            {isChecked &&
            <input/>}
            {
                isChecked ? null : <div onClick={handleClose}>block two</div>
            }
            {isClosed &&
            <input/>
            }



        </div>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you almost had the code right in the first place!

You need to render condicional  the div of the block two.

```
<div onClick={handleCheck}>block one</div>
{isChecked &&
<input/>
}

{is Closed &&
<div onClick={handleClose}>block two</div>
<input/>
}
```

It works, right?? :)

Comment: i've already done my problem, look at answer by myself

Comment: hi!! Yes, I know, but I was telling you other solution because I don't think two ternary are the best solution. Also because both of them return null if the condition is true...best!